# Iterating through dictionary and doing some stuff

Tags: c#, .net, loops, dictionary, key-value

is it possible to iterat through dictionary like this?

> 1. I want to count all dictionary items (sum every Value),
> 2. Next, for each Key I want to take their Value
> 3. Then, I want to divide every EACH Key Value with sum
> 4. And lasty I want to multiply every output from 3

I made it so it works with 1 item, but not sure how to make it so it works with every item in dictionary.

Here is sample code for 1 item:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
//this is sum
double y = 0;
foreach (var item in dic)
{
     y += item.Value;
}
//this is selected item
double x = 0;
foreach (var item in dic)
{               
    if (item.Key == "Smith")
    {
        x = item.Value;
    }
}
double z = 0;
z = x / y;
Console.WriteLine("Smith/DicSum: " + z);
```

Now I would like to multiply the Z's (each Z's for each key in dictionary).

I was thiking about making one big loop for this like:

```
for (int i=0; i<y; i++) where y is the sum for all items in dictionary and multiply z's on the end of the loop
```

but I still don't know how to grab all seperate values and divide them while not saying the specific key for each of them.

@edit
Thanks for answears but check my edit. I have a string list, let's say

> "Smith is very cool member of Smith Company"

And my program is counting the number of Smith's, so it will show x as two. Then I want to divide snumber of smiths (two) by number of all words, so it's 2/8 = 0,25. Then I want to do this with every word and multiply it so it will be 2/8*1/8*...*1/8 in this example. SO I want to multiply by a preious number from loop (from dictionary), and not by a fixed amount, that's what making this problem.

Comment: Your entire second loop is equivalent to `dic.TryGetValue("Smith", out x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var words = "Smith is very cool member of Smith Company"
    .Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var dic = new Dictionary<string, double>();

foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (dic.ContainsKey(word))
        dic[word]++;
    else
        dic[word] = 1;
}

var sum = dic.Sum(x => x.Value);
var result = dic.Values.Aggregate(1.0, (current, item) => current * (item / sum));
```

Comment: Hey, check my edit :) because in your example you multiply by fixed value not the previous loop value, sorry if i asked my question wrong.

Comment: Thanks, looking at this, it should work, but the value of result is 0,0 (checked in debugging), the sum is fine and it's 8. Don't know how to get into current/item tho.

Comment: I have edited the answer, my fault, the initial value should be 1.0 not 0.0